# Background:cover cutting off image

Tags: css, wordpress

Good evening,

I am a bit stuck on a project I am working on...

The image in the header of [this site](http://goo.gl/de0c4F), when downsizing the screen, the image doesn't respond, it simply gets cut off on the right hand side.

Can anyone help tell me what I am missing? Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want your image would be cut off then use 100% background-size but it stretch the image:

```
div{
  background: url(path.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;//but using cover would be better to look
}
```